# Swift : update of view constraints not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I do have a `UIScrollView` which holds a couple of `UIViewController`. 
For the elements inside the `UIViewController` I used AutoLayout. 
Now I'd like to change the constants of the view constraints if the current device is a iPhone 4. 
So I override `updateViewConstraints()` of the `UIViewControllers`:

```
override func updateViewConstraints() {

    if (self.view.frame.height == 480) {

        self.imageMarginLeft.constant = 40
        self.imageMarginRight.constant = 40
        self.textMarginTop.constant = 10

        println("updateViewConstraint \(self.imageMarginRight.constant)")
    }

    super.updateViewConstraints()
}
```

But even the `println` logs the correct new constant the update is not visible. 
What do I have to change in my implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127259/how-do-i-update-a-constraint-programmatically-in-swift) I had to integrate `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` before and after changing the view contstraint constant.