# changing constraints at runtime in swift

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, show-hide, nslayoutconstraint

I'm really very weak in constraints part of ios. I have gone through many reference link as shown below but still not able solve my issue.

[Hide autolayout UIView : How to get existing NSLayoutConstraint to update this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384927/hide-autolayout-uiview-how-to-get-existing-nslayoutconstraint-to-update-this-o/)

In case , i need to change the y-axis of UIView2 based on some condition. The storyboard.png shows the layout.
[image]

If condition fails UIView2 with step1, step 2 and step3 **should be visible** and it's position should also change as shown in condition1.png

[image]

If condition pass UIView2 with step1, step 2 and step3 **should not be visible** as shown in condition1.png

[image]

Please provide me steps for how to achieve the above scenario. I tried it doing but if set the constraint for UIView1 the height remains same and does not change at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make the outlet of the height constraint of both UIView and use constant property to change the height constraints like...

```
if conditionfails{
     heightconstOfView1.constant = 0
}
else{
    heightconstOfView2.constant = 0
}
```

Comment: height of  View1 changes but View2 does not move at all.

Answer (score 1):

I use outlets for constraints set on the storyboard, for divs between buttons (using old ways to set dynamic layouts). So, for large screens (iPhone 6 and above), I update the values of fixed heights (app only viewed in portrait mode). What worked for me is:

```
constHeightlogo.constant = 140 //old value = 72
///set any other updates here then force the view
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Worked like a charm.

See related here:

[Update the constant property of a constraint programmatically in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127259/how-to-update-the-constant-of-a-constraint-programmatically-in-swift)