# Removing view from layout and having other elements re-organize themselves

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I have the following screen:
[image]

If one clicks on Go Pro and buys the in app, then I'd like to remove the ads from the screen and then have both circle buttons to go to very bottom of the screen.

One possibility I thought was to have a horizontal stack view to hold the three buttons and a vertical stack view, that would first hold the horizontal stack view and then the Ads View.

Is this solution the best one or there are smarter ones?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Here's what's happening now:
With Vertical Spacing constraint to only one button:
[image]

With Vertical Spacing constraint to both buttons
[image]

Comment: just give height constraint to that admob view and make outlet and when you remove it set its constraint to 0

Comment: you can check this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804655/changing-constraints-at-runtime-in-swift/32804873  and if you are using iOS 9.0 and above stackview is good to use

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I don't think I understood it though. My AdsMob view has a height constraint of 50. Are you saying that I need to get the height constraint of Admob as an Outlet and set its constant to zero?

Comment: Alright, thank you. How do I find the height constraint of my AdView UIView Outlet? The line "adsUIView.constraints" returns a [NSLayoutConstraint]. How do I find the height one?

Comment: in storyboard ... document outline ... check this how to make outlet of constraint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356293/uitableview-and-uiview-with-keyboardwillshow/31356527#31356527

Comment: Oh, I didnt know you could turn a constraint an outlet! Thanks! Let me try this now

Comment: Ok, by setting the constant to zero, the Ads View disappeared. All good. But the buttons did not go to the bottom of the screen. Do they need any constraint to do so?

Comment: Oh, I see. It's almost there, but not quite. I will keep trying and let you know. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thanks El Captain. What is happening now is that the bottom part of the button is stretching all the way down to the bottom part of the screen. But the top part stays in the original location, so the button is stretching out. Should I programatically update the constraint that configures the top part of the button ?

Comment: I just added two new screenshots to illustrate the new issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using iOS 9.0 and above, you can use stackview else make outlet of height constraint of bottom view and set to `0` on close ad mob.

For the other issue i.e button stretch .. add one view that contains that  3 buttons and add constraints to that view ... just check below image and give constraints...

[image]

Now on close admob, just set constant of height constraint to `0`.

[image]

and the result will be

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is great! Thanks so much! Thanks for doing all that. It's working great now! So much to learn about those constraint buggers!

Comment: @FelipeCaldas happy to help you my friend :)