# Move other Views to the view which is hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

hello I am new to IOS and I am struggling in one functionality which I am trying to implement. I have a `UIViewController` in which I am showing a custom `UIView` on the top and the below I have a dynamic `TableView`. I am hiding and showing the custom UIView on some conditions but the problem is If I hide it, my table don't take a place of that view so I can see the space over there. I think I have do something with the autolayout but I am not good in autolayout so If any one can help would be great. I am attaching a demo screens here so that you can understand. What should I do to make it work so that table will take the custom UIView place when  `UIView` is hidden

[image]

This is the result I am getting If I hide the above portion Custom UIView

[image]

Comment: What constraints for the hidden 'UIView'? There are differert way to implement your idear, according to your constraints.

Comment: @TonyHan width = 414 , height = 103 , left = 0  and right = 0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32804655/changing-constraints-at-runtime-in-swift/32804873#32804873

Answer (score 5):

in order to achieve this functionality you need to do the following steps:

1. Create height constraint for your top view and save it in @IBOutlet

> @IBOutlet weak var topViewHeightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!

2. When you are hiding your top view change also your height constraint to 0 in order that the tableview will take its place .  in order to change it to 0 you just need to change the constant value to 0

> topViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0

[image]

Link for downloading a swift project that show how to do it can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B61r6TxQSBdzQlJGbFVjbzJxN0U/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I followed your steps but it isn't working for me

Comment: Also make sure that the vertical spacing between your tableView and topView is equal to 0

Comment: after you update your Constraint , you need to add **self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()** and then **self.view.layoutIfNeeded()** to update your layout

Comment: @Stephen you don't need to call those functions in order to make it work. You just need to make sure that you setup all constraints and auto layout will do the rest

Comment: @RanHassid you are right , I just notice the code are within **viewDidLoad()** which happened before **Autolayout** actually happen , so no need those method...

Comment: Working for me......