# Set UIImageView height dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, swift3

In some situations I need to remove UIImageView, but element below UIImageView has top margin in respect to UIImageView so I need to set height of UIImageView to 0 (or 1 if you can't set 0) and set `ishidden` property of UIImageView to true.

I tried this

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: imageView.frame.origin.x, y: imageView.frame.origin.y, width: 0, height: 0)
```

but nothing happens, UIImageView is not updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does it crash or does it not update?

Comment: @Adrian It's not updating.

Comment: You might want to find something else to use as a reference for the element below your `UIImageView`. Have a peek at this re: updating constraints. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127259/how-to-update-the-constant-of-a-constraint-programmatically-in-swift Also, you can `ctrl+drag` constraints from your storyboard to your `UIViewController` and create an `IBOutlet` for it and have a reference to update the constraint programmatically.